# Django built in server keep disconnecting when loading a template

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django built in server for developing a web application. Upon rendering a template for a specific web page, the server stop working without any log or warning on the console. It's just suddenly disconnected everytime i try to access that page.

After a while, i found out that if i remove a block of code which has the function of creating a dropdown list, the problem disappeared. But it's just a very simple code in order to get a list of departments, iterate it and make a dropdown list. I have seen other people do the same on the internet, so i have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the code of the view:

```py
def edit(request):
    departments = Department.objects.filter()
    # I can iterate the QuerySet normally
    for d in departments:
        print(d.id, d.name, d.department_code)

    return render(request, 'edit/edit.html', {'departments': departments})
```

and the block of code which creates a dropdown list:

```html
<select name="department1" class="department">
   <option value=""></option>
   {% for d in departments %}
       <option value="{{ d.id }}"> {{ d.name }} - {{ d.department_code }} </option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How many `Department` objects do you have in your database?

Comment: What is the exact code you remove? The snippet you've shown here shouldnt cause any issues like you describe

Comment: I suspect that you just don't have the data in the database that you are expecting.  When you say, ` It's just suddenly disconnected everytime i try to access that page.` , I'm guessing that your getting a 200 response and not a 500 or timeout.  A 200 would mean that you've processed the request correctly.  If you want to be sure you can add `assert len(departments) >= 1` just before your `render(...)` statement.

Comment: I have 18 Department objects in the database. I have iterated the departments and print out the values (as in the code in the view) and there are expected results on the console.
Also the code i removed is the block of html code i have posted up there. If i remove that block the server works normally. I know it sounds so weird that's why i'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I was using MysqlConnector API to connect to the database. I switch to mysqlclient instead and voilà, the server works beautifully now.

What i'm really mad about is i still don't know why that happened. The Django document simply said that you can use MysqlConnector API, there is no warning about any problem at all. The server also kept disconnecting without any trace or log, leaving me in the dark. It took me over 1 day of desperately debugging till i felt like there is something wrong with the connection to the database.

Anyway, thank you all for your helps, hope this can help somebody to avoid this problem as well.

P/S: It took me that long to recognized something wrong with the connection because i can still get the data from the database and print it on the console, so i didn't think there is any problem about that.